# Inconvertable types error when passing and using fragment context in listener class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

I am trying to implement and autocomplete function for an edittext in a fragment but having trouble passing the context of the fragment to the listener/textwatcher. In the constructor, it accepts the context as a parameter but brings an "inconvertable types" error when trying to link the context to the fragment.

```
`EmpAddFragment mainActivity = ((EmpAddFragment)context);`
```

Below is the code for the listener and the fragment where it is called.

**CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener.java:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener implements TextWatcher {

public static final String TAG = "CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener.java";
Context context;
View view;
Fragment fragment;

public CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                              int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence userInput, int start, int before, int count) {



    EmpAddFragment mainActivity = ((EmpAddFragment)context);

    // query the database based on the user input
    mainActivity.item = mainActivity.getItemsFromDb(userInput.toString());

    // update the adapater
    mainActivity.myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mainActivity.myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mainActivity.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, mainActivity.item);
    mainActivity.myAutoComplete.setAdapter(mainActivity.myAdapter);

   }

 }
```

**EmpAddFragment:**

```
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;


public class EmpAddFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener      {

// UI references
private EditText empNameEtxt;
private Button addButton;
private Button resetButton;
/*
 * Change to type CustomAutoCompleteView instead of AutoCompleteTextView
 * since we are extending to customize the view and disable filter
 * The same with the XML view, type will be CustomAutoCompleteView
 */
CustomAutoCompleteView myAutoComplete;

// adapter for auto-complete
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;

// for database operations
DataBaseHelper databaseH;

// just to add some initial value
String[] item = new String[] {"Please search..."};

private static final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);

DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
Calendar dateCalendar;

Employee employee = null;
private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;
private AddEmpTask task;

public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "emp_add_fragment";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    employeeDAO = new EmployeeDAO(getActivity());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_emp, container,
            false);

    findViewsById(rootView);

    setListeners();

    try{

        // instantiate database handler
        databaseH = new DataBaseHelper(getActivity());


        // autocompletetextview is in activity_main.xml
        myAutoComplete = (CustomAutoCompleteView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myautocomplete);

        // add the listener so it will tries to suggest while the user types
        myAutoComplete.addTextChangedListener(new CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener(this.getActivity()));

        // set our adapter
        myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, item);
        myAutoComplete.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //For orientation change.
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        dateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        if (savedInstanceState.getLong("dateCalendar") != 0)
            dateCalendar.setTime(new Date(savedInstanceState
                    .getLong("dateCalendar")));
    }

    return rootView;


}

private void setListeners() {

    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
            new OnDateSetListener() {

                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    dateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    dateCalendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

                }

            }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    addButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    resetButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

protected void resetAllFields() {
    empNameEtxt.setText("");

}

private void setEmployee() {
    employee = new Employee();
    employee.setName(empNameEtxt.getText().toString());

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.add_emp);
    getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.add_emp);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    if (dateCalendar != null)
        outState.putLong("dateCalendar", dateCalendar.getTime().getTime());
}

private void findViewsById(View rootView) {
    empNameEtxt = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etxt_name);


    addButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_add);
    resetButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_reset);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == null) {

    } else if (view == addButton) {
        setEmployee();

        task = new AddEmpTask(getActivity());
        task.execute((Void) null);
    } else if (view == resetButton) {
        resetAllFields();
    }
}

public class AddEmpTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Long> {

    private final WeakReference<Activity> activityWeakRef;

    public AddEmpTask(Activity context) {
        this.activityWeakRef = new WeakReference<Activity>(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        long result = employeeDAO.save(employee);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        if (activityWeakRef.get() != null
                && !activityWeakRef.get().isFinishing()) {
            if (result != -1)
                Toast.makeText(activityWeakRef.get(), "Employee Saved",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}

// this function is used in CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener.java
public String[] getItemsFromDb(String searchTerm){

      // add items on the array dynamically
      List<MyObject> products = databaseH.read(searchTerm);
      int rowCount = products.size();

      String[] item = new String[rowCount];
      int x = 0;

      for (MyObject record : products) {

        item[x] = record.objectName;
        x++;
      }

       return item;
    }
 }
```

This is the logcat when i used

```
 `EmpAddFragment mainActivity = new EmpAddFragment;
```

All other attempts output the inconvertable types error

LogCat:

```
07-23 06:49:17.828    2017-2017/com.example.autoFill E/AndroidRuntime﹕     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.autoFill, PID: 2017
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.autoFill.EmpAddFragment.getItemsFromDb(EmpAddFragment.java:209)
        at com.example.autoFill.CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener.onTextChanged(CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener.java:42)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7408)
        at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7467)
        at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:9187)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:962)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:496)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:212)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
        at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(BaseInputConnection.java:243)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:382)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**UPDATE:**

Changed my listener constructor to:

```
 public CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener(EmpAddFragment frag){
    frag = fragment;
    context = fragment.getActivity();
 }
```

and the call to:

```
 myAutoComplete.addTextChangedListener(new CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener(this));
```

But register a NullPointerException in the logcat pointing to:

```
 myAutoComplete.addTextChangedListener(new CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener(this));
```

AND:

```
context = fragment.getActivity();
```

Comment: post the `LogCat` log.

Answer (score 0):

```
 myAutoComplete.addTextChangedListener(new CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener(this.getActivity()));
```

with the line above you are not passing the fragment but the activity from where it is called so when you call:

```
EmpAddFragment mainActivity = ((EmpAddFragment)context);
```

it can't work because you are casting to EmpAddFragment an Activity instance.

so if you want to have the fragment instance change the listener constructor and pass the fragment.
if you want to have the activity then cast the context to the activity

Answer (score 0):

Change the constructor of your listener class

```
 public class CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener implements TextWatcher {

    public static final String TAG = "CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener.java";
    Context context;
    View view;
    Fragment fragment;

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener(EmpAddFragment fragment){
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.context = fragment.getActivity();
    }

    //.... rest of your listener class implementation
}
```

Use the calling method as follows where you face "inconvertible types"

```
EmpAddFragment mainFragment = ((EmpAddFragment)fragment);
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Got rid of the error but now get null pointer exception error. placed details in updated thread

Comment: NullPointer happens as the field myAutoComplete is null. Based on your comment above that NullPointer line, you have mentioned the CustomAutoCompleteView is present in activity_main.xml while you have inflated fragment_add_emp.xml. Double check with that.